# I want to make a like count for multiple users in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the like counter and want to upload result on firebase database. if another user likes the post the like counter should increment the value rather than starting from 0.

here is what my databaseReference look like `DatabaseLOLCounter.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("counter").setValue('like counter value here');`

myfirebase database structure:
[image: This is my firebasedatabase structure]

here's my viewHolder

```
viewHolder.mLOL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        processLOL=true;
        DatabaseFacepalm.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
        DatabaseAngry.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
        DatabaseNeutral.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();

            DatabaseLOL.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (processLOL)
                        {
                            if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()))
                            {
                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //if already reacted
                                //DatabaseLOLCounter.setValue(Count = Count - 1 );
                                updateLOLCounter(false,post_key);
                                DatabaseLOL.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                                processLOL=false;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //if no react
                                updateLOLCounter(true,post_key);
                                //DatabaseLOLCounter.setValue(Count = Count + 1 );
                                DatabaseLOL.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("lol");
                                processLOL=false;
                            }
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

    }
});
```

my updateLike counter looks like this (copied from somewhere)

```
 private void updateLOLCounter(final boolean increment, final String post_key) {

        DatabaseLOLCounter.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            if (mutableData.getValue() != null) {
                int value = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                if(increment)
                {
                    value++;

                } else {
                    value--;
                }
                mutableData.setValue(value);

            }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }
```

Now what should i do to set the like counter on firebase.

heres the new error im facing :
[image: heres the new error im facing]

Comment: The like value is added to firebase?

Comment: no, that's what i want to do, can you tell me?

Comment: the value incrises when you call **value++;**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple counter, however the value of the counter  will return  to 0 once the app is closed. Hence, using Firebase Transactions would be a better choice as data does not get corrupted due to concurrent updates.

Add this line before OnCreate.

```
private Firebase LOLCounter;
```

Now add the following code under the OnClicklistener.

```
viewHolder.mLOL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   LOLCounter = new Firebase("add your Firebase DB link");
   Firebase DatabaseLOLCounter = LOLCounter.child("LOL");
   DatabaseLOLCounter.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
      @Override
      public Transaction.Result doTransaction(final MutableData currentData) {
      if (currentData.getValue() == null) {
        currentData.setValue(1);
      } else {
        currentData.setValue((Long) currentData.getValue() + 1);
      }

      return Transaction.success(currentData);
  }

@Override
public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
    if (firebaseError != null) {
        Log.d("Firebase counter increment failed.");
    } else {
        Log.d("Firebase counter increment succeeded.");
    }
}
});
}
```

[Database link example.](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-UlwFxWhwI28/V9BK8FRjGUI/AAAAAAAAGMI/aVauTwYuJ0U9zaX2P37PcprCzbCYyh7-QCLcB/s1600/Firebase%2B%252B%2BConsole.png)

Comment: But how will the like counter be updated on firebase?...my updateLOLCounter isnt uploadint the counter on firebase

Comment: by looking at my firebase database structure can you tell me what should i add in "add your Firebase DB link"), im new to firebase thingy, your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: It is not possible to tell the link from your database structure. To get the link, simply login on the firebase console and open your project. The link will be present there.

Comment: i didnt get this line 

LOLCounter = new Firebase("add your Firebase DB link");

can you write full code please?

Comment: Just add that line and put in your db link.

Comment: i canno write alone "Firebase", should i write it as DatabaseReference or FirebaseDatabase. and secondly correct me if im wrong is this my DB link:DatabaseLOLCounter.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("counter")

Comment: Have you initialised LOLCounter before onCreate. `private Firebase LOLCounter;`. Also I have added an example image of db link.

Comment: i have initialised private DatabaseReference DatabaseLOLCounter; only
.There is no thing like "private Firebase LOLCounter;" Firebase keyword is Red

Comment: Did you `import com.firebase.client.Firebase;`  and `import com.firebase.client.*;`

Comment: ok, i hadn't included the library for that, i have now. now the problem is with link. can you help me whats the link of my firebase db?

Comment: Check the end of the answer. I have added an example image. The link containing firebaseio.com is the db link.

Comment: hey I am still unable t get rid of errors. can you come on teamViewr or something? I'll be very thankful to you

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your errors in your question as an edit.

Comment: ive attached it. check it

Comment: It seems like you haven't put in the link. I had made an app with the same feature. You could look into the source code of it. https://pastebin.com/BDQbNc19

Answer (score 0):

It should be declare as a and all firebase client must mention before

```
  @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_news_feed, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}
```

> But we need to consider everything is under adapter to integrate it in post with recycle view adapter

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int viewType) {

    ImageUploadInfoFeed UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(viewType);
    holder.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());
    holder.plantType.setText(UploadInfo.getType());
    holder.plantDescription.setText(UploadInfo.getDescription());
    Glide.with(context).load(UploadInfo.getImageURL()).into(holder.imageView);


    holder.mLOL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            processLOL=true;

            DatabaseFacepalm.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
           // DatabaseAngry.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
          //  DatabaseNeutral.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();

            DatabaseLOL.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (processLOL)
                    {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()))
                        {
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //if already reacted
                            //DatabaseLOLCounter.setValue(Count = Count - 1 );
                            updateLOLCounter(false,post_key);
                            DatabaseLOL.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                            processLOL=false;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //if no react
                            updateLOLCounter(true,post_key);
                            //DatabaseLOLCounter.setValue(Count = Count + 1 );
                            DatabaseLOL.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("lol");
                            processLOL=false;
                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    });




}




@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
}
```

and These variable of button will deleclre as

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener {
    public View view;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView imageNameTextView;
    public TextView plantType;
    public TextView plantDescription;
    public Button mLOL;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context=itemView.getContext();
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageVieww);
        mLOL=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeButton);
        imageNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantName_feed);
        plantType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plant_feed_type);
        plantDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plant_feed_desc);


    }
    @Override
  public void onClick(View v){


    }

    }



  }
```